# Font awesome Vue icon flipping if code is moved

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, font-awesome

I have some navigation buttons with fontawesome icons. 'Previous' has a left facing arrow. 'Next' has a right facing arrow. When left in their original order everything works as expected. When I rearrange the buttons, the 'Prev' left arrow icon flips to be facing right.
I have tried using different icons (chevron-left/right) and I get the same behavior.

Is this normal behavior that I am not aware of, or a bug, or something else entirely?

Order 1 :

```
        <button v-if="showPrev()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-outline-info" @click="prev()"><i class="icon-large fas fa-arrow-left"></i>  PREV </button>
        <!-- Spacer --><div v-else class="col-md-2"></div>

        <button v-if="showSubmit()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-success" @click="next()"> SUBMIT  <i class="icon-large fas fa-check"></i></button>
        <button v-else-if="showFinish()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-outline-danger" @click="finish()"> FINISH  <i class="icon-large fas fa-check"></i></button>
        <!-- Spacer --><div v-else class="col-md-2"></div>

        <button v-if="showNext()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-outline-info" @click="next()"> NEXT  <i class="icon-large fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        <!-- Spacer --><div v-else class="col-md-2"></div>
```

[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS7XW.png)

Order 2 :

```
        <button v-if="showPrev()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-outline-info" @click="prev()"><i class="icon-large fas fa-arrow-left"></i>  PREV </button>
        <!-- Spacer --><div v-else class="col-md-2"></div>

        <button v-if="showNext()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-outline-info" @click="next()"> NEXT  <i class="icon-large fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        <!-- Spacer --><div v-else class="col-md-2"></div>

        <button v-if="showSubmit()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-success" @click="next()"> SUBMIT  <i class="icon-large fas fa-check"></i></button>
        <button v-else-if="showFinish()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-outline-danger" @click="finish()"> FINISH  <i class="icon-large fas fa-check"></i></button>
        <!-- Spacer --><div v-else class="col-md-2"></div>
```

[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQSaA.png)

MCVE attempt :
(Font-awesome icons aren't displaying in SO snippets making reproduction impossible. If I'm missing something, comment and I'll edit)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card p-0 mt-5">
  <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    <button class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-outline-info"><i class="icon-large fas fa-arrow-left"></i>  PREV </button>

    <button class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-outline-info"> NEXT  <i class="icon-large fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>

    <button class="col-md-2 mb-3 btn btn-success"> SUBMIT  <i class="icon-large fas fa-check"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not normal behavior, you might have some CSS changing the layout. Can you throw together a running sample that reproduces this issue? Can't debug with just images.

Comment: I'll throw together an MCV tomorrow morning and edit the post.

Comment: I am having trouble getting any font-awesome icons to appear in SO Snippets at all, making the bug impossible to MCVE. I will keep trying and editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the 'vue-if' statements. When a vue-if fails and the button is not displayed, the next button to be rendered is displaying the icon that wasn't displayed because of the vue-if.

Simply wrapping the button/icon combo in a div and performing the vue-if check there solves the problem.

```
        <div v-if="showPrev()" class="col-md-2 mb-3 ">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-info" @click="prev()"><i class="icon-large fas fa-arrow-left"></i>  PREV </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Also, noticing you're using functions in your `v-if` statement. Generally bad practice, I'd recommend using [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) or [data](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods). That way, you have built-in reactivity without doing anything extra.

Comment: I was under the impression that the only difference between a computed property and a method in Vue was that a computed property was cached. The website you linked even states as such. The showX() methods are calculating whether or not an element should be shown based on rule patterns that change on the fly, making cached values irrelevant. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No, you're correct, and I misguided you with that reactivity bit -- both a function and a computed prop *will* update reactively. The idea with computed properties is that you could have any amount of logic being done in your `showNext` method and use it in multiple places (say a loop) without doing any extra work. If you're just doing a simple if statement or something else and only ever calling it once, there will essentially be no difference, but functions are generally reserved for event handlers and doing things. Also makes code easier to follow imo.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're not doing anything explicitly wrong, it's just a pattern I've found useful to follow. :) [Also, see this reference.](https://flaviocopes.com/vue-methods-watchers-computed-properties/)

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for you feedback though. I will keep this in mind in future as I am sure there are places in my codebase that could benefit from computed properties.